# Appending a line to a plot in matplotlib, axis glitch

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to be able to do something like this:

```python
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: plt.ion()
In [3]: line = plt.plot([1,2],[1,2])
In [4]: plt.close('all')
In [5]: plt.plot([1,2],[1,4])
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x6e71e30>]
In [6]: ax = plt.gca()
In [7]: ax.lines.append(line[0])
In [8]: plt.draw()
```

This seems to do what I ask. The problem is, if I try to move around on the plot the line that was appended is independent of the axis. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I don't think lines are meant to be moved from one axes to another like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upfront: I don't know whether you can append like that; however, you can certainly abstract what you are doing into a function and pass it axes to work on:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def add_lines(ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    return ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
```

Comment: That's too bad. It would be nice to do because `line` would contain any label, color, and style associated with it on the first plot. But you're right, it's relatively simple to write a function to append it.